# Change file to correct URL in Yii framework

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii, yii-routing

Index path of my yii application is "site.com/www/index.php". How to write htaccess file to open my application by url: "site.com" ?

Answer (score 0):

You should simply read this :
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#hiding-x-23x

Comment: Where to put the file that given in the article? In the root directory? How I should set path to index.php?